# How to configure osm2po to use the specified maxCost in TspDefaultMatrix

Tags: osm2po

**The problem**

I am using *osm2po*'s `TspDefaultMatrix` to create a cost (time) matrix:

```
new TspDefaultMatrix(graph, vertexIds, maxCost, Log.stdout(Log.LEVEL_LOG), properties)
```

Where `properties` contains:

```
findShortestPath: false
ignoreRestrictions: false
ignoreOneWays: false
heuristicFactor: 1.0
```

I tried many value for `maxCost` (`0`, `1`, `2`, `Float.MAX_VALUE`). Except for `maxCost = 0`, I always get this in the log:

```
DEBUG  Heuristic MaxCost set to 0.2134047
```

followed by some:

```
WARN   Matrix [8][9] unreachable!
WARN   Matrix [8][3] unreachable!
```

because, indeed, some of the vertexId are more than `0.2134047` hours appart.

**The question**

I want to know how this value (`0.2134047`) is calculated and how I can effectively tell `TspDefaultMatrix` to use my `maxCost`.

By the ways, I did not found (was not searching a lot) the osm2po source code. Is it available ? I would have been able to answer my question myself.

**EDIT:**

By the way, I was using version `4.8.8` of *osm2po* to build the `.gph` file and at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `maxCost` refers to one path of many. It does not denote the entire TSP-Route. osm2po uses some kind of heuristic here, assuming that after some full traverserls the longest path between two arbitrary points is found. This parameter is (sorry for that - I've forgotten) not published. The default value is set to 3. Meaning that after the third full traversel, the maxCost will be limited to the longest path found so far.
The reason why I use this heuristic is simple: Assume you are going to calculate a matrix for a very short distance on a very large country/continent. If there is sth. wrong with the input parameters (unreachable vertices, e.g.) the algo would try to find a solution on the entire graph instead of a limited region.
Here is the parameter you can play with:

```
int fullSearchLoops = Integer.parseInt(
  params.getProperty("matrix.fullSearchLoops", "3"));
```

Increasing this to e.g. 10 should eliminate your warnings.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your very fast answer! I just tried it. When I set `matrix.fullSearchLoops = 10`, it works like a charms, without even any impact on the performances. And btw, thank you for this great, fast, usefull and clean tool you made.

Comment: And what about the project sources; are they available ? Is there any concern regarding the usage of this project in a commercial application ?

Comment: one very important question: do you get different results now?

Comment: It's closed source (freeware) but you can use it for commercial applications.

Comment: The two results are exactly the same (with `matrix.fullSearchLoops` equals to `3` and `10`). Except, obviously, for those places in the matrix where I previously had some `NaN` due to the unreachable vertex pairs, now I have a good value. Can you tell me if there is a rule (like `nbVertices / 2` or something) I can follow when choosing a number to put in the `matrix.fullSearchLoops` property ?

Comment: There is no rule. It just bases on the assumption that reverse paths have nearly the same costs as their forward ones. And of course on that the longest path between two abitrary points is never part of an optimal solution.

Comment: well, "never" is only an assumtion. Would rather say in 99,9% of all cases.